# JavaScript Fetch and Flask Communication

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fetch-api

So I'm trying to use the JavaScript Fetch API with Flask to get a string and Fetch successfully reaches Flask with no issues, but can't get a text response from Flask. Here is my code:

Javascript:

```js
fetch("/validatelogin", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
        body: JSON.stringify({"username": credentials[0],"password": credentials[1]}, null, 4)
    })
    .then(res => Response.body)
    .then(body => console.log(body))
```

and the python:

```py
@app.route('/validatelogin', methods=['POST'])
def login(): 
    users = loads(post(
        'http://localhost:8000/sql',
        headers=headers,
        auth=HTTPBasicAuth('nonono','rnoonononoo'),
        data=f"SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = {request.json['username']} AND password = {request.json['password']}"
    ).text)[0]["result"]
    
    if users != []: 
        response = make_response("yes", 200)
        response.mimetype = "text/plain"
        return response
    
    response = make_response("no", 200)
    response.mimetype = "text/plain"
    return response
```

Im trying to get a text response from flask using js fetch. I tried changing mimetype, changing status code, and using XHR but all it does is return `undefined`

sorry if the answer is simple or something because i'm really new to javascript and python.

Comment: I saw it in another post so probably

Comment: Looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text could you try `.then((res) => res.text())` instead of `.then(res => Response.body)`?

Comment: When the request is made are you able to look in the network tab of the developer tools in your browser and see what response you get for the request?

Comment: I get undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer thanks to [this medium article](https://towardsdatascience.com/talking-to-python-from-javascript-flask-and-the-fetch-api-e0ef3573c451). It seems that using `Response.Body` was what made it break. Instead you should use `Response.text` to get the text

here is my updated code

```js
fetch("/validatelogin", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
        body: JSON.stringify({"username": creds[0],"password": creds[1]}, null, 4)
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.text();
    }).then(function (text) {
        console.log(text)
    });
```

and i didn't do anything for the python code

Answer (score 0):

.then(res => res.text).then(data => console.log(data);

Comment: it still returns undefined

Comment: `text` appears to be a method, so `.then(res => res.text)` should probably be `.then(res => res.text())`.

Comment: thank you but i've found the answer already